# timer for user response in bot framework composer

Tags: timer, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I need to set a timer for a user response in my bot framework composer (DOTNET),
for example
bot: what is your name?
user: no answer
(after 5 min) bot: are you still there?
user: no answer
(after 5 min) bot: I'm ending this dialog, thank you!

any help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be using [Proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). Unfortunately; this is not something that is currently built into Composer. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6664) to have that implemented. You should be able to modify the runtime, but this would be non-trivial. You can find some more insightful info on [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5397).